# Strange php behaviour on some text field input

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for a small project. I went to make some tests to see how well i am protected against sql injection. After getting strange redirects, i made a very simple application to see if the result is the same. And it is. What i talk about. I have this view:

```
<form action="/test" method="post">
<input type="text" name="d">
<input type="text" name="c">
<button type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>

<? 
    if(isset($_POST['d'])) echo $_POST['d'];
    echo '<br>';
    if(isset($_POST['c'])) echo $_POST['c'];

?>
```

And a simple controller that binds to it's index function to load this view. I get very strange behaviour on some particular input in the fields. For example if i want to tap 1=1 in one of the fields the page goes to a 404 error, outside my project, to the site that offers the host service i use. Tested some types on inputs. In the second input i can type anything. But in first if it's like integer=integer it goes crazy. 1=1a is ok, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You might be dealing with a [SQL injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) problem here. Your hosting service might have some sql injection prevention software which produces the 404.

Do you query your database with the data that is filled in? 
If you do, make sure you [escape the data](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

The fact that you can fill anything into the second field is probally because you hash the data.

example:

```
echo md5("1=1");//50347a3f14aea923e9f8eac867fd3bb1
```

Comment: I dont query. index.php is the code snip you see above. That is all. And I don't md5 on any of fields, tho second is not affected. I discovered "=", also redirects me random.

On another host it is ok.